# How to subset data.frames stored in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset, lapply

I created a list and I stored one data frame in each component. Now I would like to filter those data frames keeping only the rows that have NA in a specific column. I would like the result of this operation to be another list containing data frames with only those rows having NA in that column.

Here is some code to clarify what I am saying. Assume `d1` and `d2` are my data frames

```
set.seed(1)

d1<-data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=c(rep(2006, times=4),NA))
d2<-data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(2007, 2007, NA, NA, 2007))  

print(d1)
 a    b
 1.3011543 2006
 0.3780023 2006
-0.3101449 2006
-1.3927445 2006
-1.0726218   NA

print(d2)
a    b
1 2007
2 2007
3   NA
4   NA
5 2007
```

which I place in a list with a for loop

```
ls<-list()

for (i in 1:2){ 

  str<-paste("d", i, sep="")
  dat<-get(str)
  ls[[str]]<-dat

}
```

Now I would like to filter each list component so to leave only rows of column b that contain NA. To do this I tried using the following command, knowing from the beginning it would have failed. My problem is that I don't know if `subset()` is the right function to use and, in case it is, I don't know how to qualify each data frame (that is, the first element of the subset function)

```
lsNA<-lapply(ls, subset(ls, is.na(b)))
```

Can you please help me get past my severe limitations?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`lapply`'s second argument is a function (`subset`) and extra arguments to `subset` are passed as the `...` arguments to `lapply`. Hence:

```
my.ls <- list(d1 = d1, d2 = d2)
my.lsNA <- lapply(my.ls, subset, is.na(b))
```

(I am also showing you how to easily create the list of data.frames without using `get`, and recommend you don't use `ls` as a variable name since it is also the name of a rather common function.)

Comment: suppose instead of filtering NA I want to keep only the first column of each data frame, what command can I use? I thought that the command _my.ls2<-lapply(my.ls, my.ls[,1])_ would have worked but it doesn't. This makes me think I still haven't understood something about lapply...

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the question in @Riccardo's last comment, try:

```
lapply(my.ls, "[", 1)
```

or alternately:

```
lapply(my.ls, "[[", 1)
```

depending on whether you want the output to be a list of dataframes or a list of vectors.

Comment: This works for subsetting **columns**: `lapply(my.ls, "[", 1:2)` would retain the first and second column from all the dataframes within the list.

Answer (score 0):

Era can also use the tidyverse:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map(my.ls, ~filter(.x, is.na(b)))
```