# Work with data frames stored in lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

With this question I would like to extend and generalize the discussion started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952880). This is for the benefit of those, like me, who are still in trouble when have to use lapply.

Suppose I have the data frames `d1` and `d2` which I store in the list `my.ls`

```
d1<-data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=c(rep(2006, times=4),NA), c=letters[1:5])
d2<-data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(2007, 2007, NA, NA, 2007), c=letters[6:10])
my.ls<-list(d1=d1, d2=d2)
```

How can I obtain another list featuring the same data frames for which I keep only the first and third columns? I tried the following, but it didn't work

```
my.ls.sub<-lapply(my.ls, my.ls[,c(1,3)])
```

What if then, I not only want to subset the data frames, but I also want to know what are the `unique` values in the columns I am extracting? (In other words, here I would create two vectors for every data frame which could be free or stored in a list of lists). For the latter point I am not able to suggest anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
lapply(my.ls, "[", ,c(1,3))
```

Or editing a little bit your code yields:

```
lapply(my.ls, function(x) x[, c(1,3)])
```

### Edit

Since @Matthew Plourde already answered the second part of your question using `lapply`, then I give you an alternative way to do it using `rapply` which is the recursive version of `lapply`.

```
rapply(lapply(my.ls, "[", ,c(1,3)), unique, how="list")
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you also be able to resolve the second part of the question with lapply?

Answer (score 2):

You were close: `lapply(my.ls, '[', c(1,3))`. This calls the indexing function `[` on each `data.frame` with the additional argument `c(1,3)`, specifying the first and third column.

Equivalently, you could call `lapply(my.ls, '[', -2)` to remove the second column.

But I would recommend the more intelligible `lapply(my.ls, subset, select=c(1,3))`.

To go directly from your original list to the a list of which values are unique in each column of each `data.frame`, you could use nested `lapply` statements like so:

```
lapply(my.ls, function(d) lapply(d[c(1,3)], unique))
```

Comment: @Matthew Plourde Yes, super fast. Thanks! What about the second part of the question? Can I do that with lapply?