# subset dataframe by column in a list based on a vector of column names and summarize the columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, lapply

I have a list of 40 dataframes. A subset for example would look like:

```
d1<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c("2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007"), d=c(6,7,8,9,10), e=c(11,12,13,14,15))
d2<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c("2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007"), d=c(6,7,8,9,10), e=c(11,12,13,14,15))
d3<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c("2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007"), d=c(6,7,8,9,10), e=c(11,12,13,14,15))

mylist <- list(l1=d1, l2=d2, l3=d3)
```

I want to subset the database based on a vector of column names:

```
subset_colnames <- c("a", "d", "e")
```

Such that after subsetting dataframe should look like this:

```
#Subsetting dataframes based on columns:
d1<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c("2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007"))
d2<-data.frame(d=c(6,7,8,9,10), b=c("2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007"))
d3<-data.frame(e=c(11,12,13,14,15), b=c("2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007"))

mylist_filtered = list(l1=d1, l2=d2, l3=d3)
```

Eventually I want to summarize the column names in `subset_columns` for each dataframe in the list like so:

```
d1 %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(a), n = n())

d2 %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(d), n = n())

d3 %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(e), n = n())
```

I would like to do this using `lapply`, looked at solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952880/how-to-subset-data-frames-stored-in-a-list?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957724/work-with-data-frames-stored-in-lists?noredirect=1&lq=1) but my operation is slightly unique in that I want to subset columns based on a character vector

Comment: column b will be present in all 3 df?

Comment: yes, it will be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Map`, with a customized function that takes a data frame from the list and a column name from the *subset_columns* and summarize it; To evaluate the character name as a actual column in `summarize`, use the `rlang/tidyeval` syntax:

```
library(dplyr); library(rlang);

cust_mean <- function(df, col) {
    df %>% 
        group_by(b) %>% 
        summarise(mean = mean(!!sym(col)), n = n())
}

Map(cust_mean, mylist, subset_colnames)
#$l1
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#       b  mean     n
#  <fctr> <dbl> <int>
#1   2006   2.0     3
#2   2007   4.5     2

#$l2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#       b  mean     n
#  <fctr> <dbl> <int>
#1   2006   7.0     3
#2   2007   9.5     2

#$l3
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#       b  mean     n
#  <fctr> <dbl> <int>
#1   2006  12.0     3
#2   2007  14.5     2
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a simple function for the list that I mostly understood except for `summarise(mean = mean(!!sym(col)`, what does `!!sym(col)` do? Also, `Map` says it is a wrapper around `mapply` but I don't get the same result if I use `Map(cust_mean, mylist, subset_colnames)`

Comment: `col` is a string, but `summarize` requires a symbol to be evaluated as a column, `!!sym(col)` is to evaluate `col` as a column, as if you have typed `summarize(mean = mean(a))` for instance. `Map` is equivalent to `mapply(..., simplify=FALSE)`. To make `mapply` work, you need `mapply(cust_mean, mylist, subset_colnames, SIMPLIFY = F)`.

Comment: Thanks! I get it. One last question. Can we collapse the list (`l1, l2, l3`) into one dataframe with one, common header and add a column `eg_variable` which indicates list element name  `l1, l2, l3` in each row?

Comment: You can use `bind_rows` on the list with `.id` parameter. `bind_rows(Map(cust_mean, mylist, subset_colnames), .id="eg_variable")`

Comment: yes, I figured it out, I can also just `do.call(rbind, df_w_means)` which conveniently gives the list names as row.names

Comment: What r version do you use? It doesn't seem to keep the list names if I run the same.

Comment: R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21). Which one do you use?

Comment: Hmm. I have R 3.3.3. Looks like the behavior of `rbind` has changed (in a good way). Possibly time to update R.